# Prestashop Currency issue when try to get it using webservice

Tags: web-services, api, prestashop, currency, prestashop-1.6

From Prestashop admin I have added new currency (currency which display values with comma like 26,51) and place an order. It shows prices in new currency (see image 1) but when I get order using web service, It does not get price in new currency with comma, It shows in dots instead of comma. (see image 2)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: And the issue is?

Comment: I want same value in API which is display in admin. Like in admin its display as 26,51 (with comma) but in API its 26.51 (without comma)

Comment: You have to 'convert' with a simple string replace. All the prices are stored with dot in database :)

Comment: @sarcom Thanks for your reply. Actually I develop one app for Prestashop admin. And in that one of my user got issue because of in their site price came with , (Comma) instead of . (dot). So I just make sure is this possible in Prestashop and if yes then How I can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In PrestaShop database, the price values are stored as actual values (float numbers). To show them at any interface, PrestaShop passes the values to a predefined function and then display the output of that function only.

The function that Prestashop uses is

```
Tools::displayPrice()
```

You can also use it to convert the actual float value to the proper formatted currency value.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to preprocess the value you get from the web service to apply the appropriate locale language:

```
$locale = ( isset($_COOKIE['locale']) ) ? 
        $_COOKIE['locale'] : 
        $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

function number_format_locale($number,$decimals=2) {
$locale = localeconv();
return number_format($number,$decimals,
           $locale['decimal_point'],
           $locale['thousands_sep']);
```

}

Use the function number_format_locale() to convert the total price to French.

French: bonne chance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom method that returns the value as you want, make an override of `Order` class (create a new php file in `prestashop/override/classes/order` named `Order.php`):

```
class Order extends OrderCore{
    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null){
        $this->webserviceParameters['fields']['total_paid'] = array(
            'getter' => 'getWsTotalPaid'
        );

        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);
    }

    public function getWsTotalPaid(){
        return str_replace('.', ',', $this->total_paid);
    }
}
```

Obviously you can 'reformat' all fields that you want, but pay attention to parent settings.